# Techincal limitations of offscreen canvas performance

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Is there such a thing as a maximum size for an off-screen canvas? Or perhaps a point where writing to it/getting image data from it starts substantially (exponentially?) affecting performance?

Say you're coding a Google maps equivalent; could you render a complete map of New York to it, at say, 100.000px by 100.000px?

Comment: Surely this will vary from device to device.

Comment: Perhaps even browser to browser, I have no clue, hence the question.

Comment: If you're curious, you can google the max canvas size for each browser. I haven't done it in a while but it's well below 100k x 100k.  In practice, I've seen performance degrade when there are 10 offscreen canvases the same size as the onscreen canvas.  But quite frankly, good performance is a result of good design--not a result of how big your canvas is  ;)